# Does any bios manufacturer make use of an alternative terminology for the legacy/UEFI option?

Tags: bios, uefi

Despite extensive googling and in depth reading of the user's guide, I'm still unable  to find (surely, it's my fault ...) a way to switch the bios from legacy to uefi mode on a MSI H310M PRO-VDH (2018) 
[MSI H310M PRO-VDH](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/H310M-PRO-VDH) mother board;
therefore I'm wordenring if I'm barking up the wrong tree, chasing an options differentely named by the manifacturer.

Does any bios manufacturer make use of an alternative terminology for the legacy/UEFI option ?

By the way, setting "[UEFI] CD/DVD", "[UEFI] hard disk", etc. in the boot sequence does not modify the bios "global" mode; any hint about my specific situation is very welcomed too.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's called: [CSM or Compatibility Support Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) is something that allows booting in legacy BIOS mode on UEFI systems.

From Wikipedia:

> The Compatibility Support Module (CSM) is a component of the UEFI
>   firmware that provides legacy BIOS compatibility by emulating a BIOS
>   environment, allowing legacy operating systems and some option ROMs
>   that do not support UEFI to still be used.